# ternary operator based on if else

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

If i have following if else statement

```
if a.present? && b.value == 'N'
 b = test
elsif a.present? && b.value == 'Y'
 b = guest
end
```

I can write ternary operation for this

```
b = (a.present? && b.value == 'N') ? "test" : "guest"
```

but in this ternary oprator i am not looking for condition b.value == 'Y' and it could be something else 'd' or 'e'.

How do i update ternary operator so it verifies both conditions in if and elsif?

Comment: Don't force use of a ternary. If you have to jump through hoops to use them, then you're probably forcing a poor use-case. And you'll need 2 ternarys to replicate that if-else structure.

Comment: @Carcigenicate is right, I would not replace that if else statement with a ternary...

Comment: Ternary statement only replaces if else conditions, not if elsif. If you can't guarantee that your b.value is only 'N' or 'Y', you can't use ternary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For something like this you might want to use a simple look-up table to eliminate some of the logic:

```
EQUIVALENT = {
  'Y' => 'guest',
  'N' => 'test'
}

if (a.present?)
  b = EQUIVALENT[b.value] || b
end
```

The `|| b` part may not be necessary if non-mapped `b` values are ignored.

Comment: This is indeed the way to go. Maybe I would use postfix `if`, within this `EQUIVALENT` constant it won’t be looking cramped.

Comment: You just love postfix `if` too much. I avoid using them on anything longer than a single keyword, like `next if ...` or `return unless ...` since anything more involved than that tends to be less immediately obvious.

Comment: You can always get a bit adventurous and do `b = EQUIVALENT[a.present? && b.value] || b` if you really want a one-liner.

Comment: No, to produce oneliners should never be a goal, that is evident even to me.

Comment: That representation avoids the trailing `if`, there's no "surprises", because it's quite clear the lookup depends on two factors both present in side the `[...]` call. Moving one condition to the end is *sneaky*.

Comment: lets make it more confusing `a.present? && b =  EQUIVALENT[b.value] || b`. No `if`, one liner (horrible code practice) **Seems Perfect**

Comment: @engineersmnky I'm sure there's a more optimal expression of this when the greater context in which this code operates in is taken into account. Names like `a` and `b` are pretty opaque. Just as I try to avoid trailing `if`s, "surprise" assignment is also a good thing to side-step.

Comment: @tadman I apologize if the extremely facetious nature of my comment was unclear.

Comment: @engineersmnky We've all got to clear those snark buffers out before there's an overflow. I totally understand.

Comment: @tadman: It's not really a one-liner if you need to define `EQUIVALENT` before. Also, your `b = .... || b` code isn't equivalent to the OP's code because it always sets `b` even if `a` isn't present.

Comment: @EricDuminil It just sets `b` back to `b`, so it's a no-op that way.

Comment: @tadman: Just wondering, is there any case for which `b = b` could be dangerous or at least do something unexpected?

Comment: @EricDuminil The only case I can think of is where `b=` is a method in that context and it does something with the input. If it's a variable I don't think it's possible to do anything at all other than assign it.

Answer (score 4):

```
b = case b.value
    when 'N' then test
    when 'Y' then guest
    end if a.present?
```

This is the only DRY answer here so far.

Comment: You could take it further and extract `case` to a method.

Comment: This is on the right track, but in this form it's super cramped. Tacking a trailing `if` on a `case` is technically valid, but also super confusing.

Comment: *Tisk* *Tisk* violates ruby style rules https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-multiline-if-modifiers

Comment: @engineersmnky I am an active rubocop-hater, btw.

Comment: While Rubocop can be overly strict, it's code like this that the Rubocop people put into their test cases. The "Principle of Least Surprise" is something you should at least try to adhere to.

Comment: Hahaha I am an active readability lover. Imagine if this was less trivial and I told you all the wonderful things I was going to do for you and how I was going to make your life fantastic and great and you were super excited about how amazing everything could be. Then at the very end I mumbled *"if you sell me your soul"* (that's kind of where this is headed). Where as if I started with that you probably would have cut me off right there.

Comment: @engineersmnky this is compact and readable, even more, it forms almost proper rectangle out of the code, which is indeed a valuable bonus :)

Comment: @engineersmnky to tell the truth, this postfix condition is the most realistic statement I ever met in Ruby. ❤ Mephistopheles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary operator. It doesn't mean you should do it, though:

```
a.present? && (b.value == 'N' ? b = 'test' : b.value == 'Y' && b = 'guest')
```

Here's a small test:

```
class Object
  def present?
    true
  end
end

class NilClass
  def present?
    false
  end
end

a = true

class B
  attr_accessor :value
end

b = B.new
b.value = 'Y'

a.present? && (b.value == 'N' ? b = 'test' : b.value == 'Y' && b = 'guest')

p b
# "guest"
```

Answer (score -1):

I would not insist on the ternary operator but extract the common `a.present?` test in an outer `if` and then write the rest of the code using [`if` modifiers](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Modifier+if+and+unless):

```
if a.present? 
    b = test if b.value == 'N'
    b = guest if b.value == 'Y'
end
```

To me, it seems much easier to read this way.